# How to write a Junit test case for a method in springboot without hardcoding

Tags: java, junit

New to `junit` test case and want to know the test case for my code here
without hardcoding values.

My code is

```
public JSONObject getListOfAllForms() {

    List<Forms> forms = FormName.getInstance().getformList();
    int totalNumberOfforms = 0;
    List<String> formIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < forms.size(); i++) {
            form formOb = forms.get(i);
            formIds.add(formOb.getformId());
            totalNumberOfforms = forms.size();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject formsListObject = new JSONObject();
    formsListObject.put("formIds", formIds);
    formsListObject.put("totalNumberOfforms", totalNumberOfforms);
    return formsListObject;
}
```

My controller code is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new/getforms/{formid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public JSONObject getFormByFormId(@PathVariable("formid") String formid) {
    return newFormName.getformByformId(formid);
}
```

Comment: what values do you don't want to hardcode?

Comment: The whole things makes not much sense, you are giving a `getListOfAllForms` method, but the Controller calls another method `getformByformId`. What exactly do you want to test?

Comment: I will list of all forms with form id in local host as "/new/getforms/formid @FlorianSchaetz

Comment: Still, no clue what you want to test. No clue what the methods above have to do with your intended test, sorry. Again, step 1: WHICH method do you want to test?

Comment: getListOfAllForms() this is the method I want to test @FlorianSchaetz

Comment: In that case we don't need the controller code. Inject a custom `FormName` inside `FormName.getInstance()` (or even better, make use of Spring DI framework!), prepare it with predefined data and test it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test `getListOfAllForms` Your problem is basically this line...

```
List<Forms> forms = FormName.getInstance().getformList();
```

This line couples your `FormName` hard into your method. This is bad.

A better way would be to provide the `FormName` instance when instantiating your class, for example, let's assume the name of your class was `MyClass`..

```
private FormName formName;

public MyClass(FormName formName) {
     this.formName = formName;
}
```

This can be used via Spring or manually. Via Spring your `FormName` instance just needs to be a bean, then you can add `@Autowired` to the constructor if `MyClass` itself is a bean.

What is the advantage now? Easy, for a test case, you can now do the simple thing...

```
public void someGreatTestName() {
    FormName formName = ...; // either create a new, fake one or mock one (see below)
    JSONObject object = new MyClass(formName).getListOfAllForms();

    // now test that the object is correct
}
```

Doing this means you can inject a fake or mock `FormName` there, which will return the data you want for the test and so remove the need to have an actual "live" `FormName` there. In other words, you can fake/mock the dependency to the `FormName`. This way, your test uses test data and you don't have to hardcode the live values there.

Mocking can be done easily via Mockito, for example, I suggest giving it a try, but in this case, simply creating a new "fake" `FormName` may suffice.